# Extract IP from IAsyncResult UDP

Tags: sockets, udp, asyncsocket

I want to extract IP address from an object of `IAsyncResult` UDP in 
`EndReceive` Method (IAsyncResult ar)

If it's possible, How can I do that?

Here the code:

```
public void End_Receive(IAsyncResult ir)
{
        //Here I need the sender IP
        ServerSocket.EndReceive(ir);
        ReceivedMessage =  System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: provide some code you tried.

Comment: Your title mentions TCP but your question mentions UDP. Which are you actually using?

Comment: So sorry ,I mean UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using TCP, or connected UDP, use the `Socket.LocalEndPoint` and `Socket.RemoteEndPoint` properties.

If you are using connection-less UDP, you should be using `Begin/EndReceiveFrom()` instead of `Begin/EndReceive()`. The callback provides an `EndPoint` for the sender.

Either way, given an `EndPoint` object, cast it to an `IPEndPoint` and use its `Address` property to access the IP address.